# Javascript replacing characters

Tags: javascript, replace, split, character

I have set up a table in which you enter a search term and it opens a amazon link, however to get multiple keywords I need to add an +.

i have used  `var removeSymb = split(' ').join('+');`  to replace it with a space however the link does not work and needs the `+`.

**Update:**

```
var url = "www.amazon"+country+"/gp/community-content-search/results/ref=cm_srch_q_rtr/?qu‌​ery="+keyword1+"&search-alias=community-reviews&Go.x=-646&Go.y=-262&idx.asin="+as‌​in+"&tag=amazon-review0a-21";
```

I have a form with asin, country and then a form to enter keywords this is the final string:

`var finalAddress1 = "amazon"+country+"/gp/community-content-search/results/…;`

For the search to have multiple keywords you need to add + between them but I need to remove this so you use space but the `+` is entered in the hyperlink

How do I do this?

Comment: this `"hello world demo".split(' ').join('+');` should work? I am not clear on what the issue with the link is

Comment: the link needs the + included to work my code removed the + from everything.

Comment: ok so i have a form with asin, country and then a form to enter keywords  this is the final string  var finalAddress1 = "http://www.amazon"+country+"/gp/community-content-search/results/ref=cm_srch_q_rtr/?query="+keyword1+"&search-alias=community-reviews&Go.x=-646&Go.y=-262&idx.asin="+asin+"&tag=amazon-review0a-21";   for the search to have multiple keywords you need to add + between them but i need to remove this so you use space vut the + is entered in the hyperlink

Comment: how do i share without using all the characters up?

Comment: What is the expected output to look? I can see the input and that is better now but what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: http://anvilwebdesign.co.uk/ i uploaded it to this

Comment: no because it is "www.amazon"+country+"/gp/community-content-search/results/ref=cm_srch_q_rtr/?query="+keyword1+"&search-alias=community-reviews&Go.x=-646&Go.y=-262&idx.asin="+asin+"&tag=amazon-review0a-21";   i'm changing the specific parts

Comment: you can enter multiple keywords into the one field. but you have to add a + betweeen then for example "customer+service". I want it to work were you enter "customer service" but the + is added into the link

Comment: both answers below should work `var keyword ="customer service".replace(/\s/g,'+'); or var keyword="customer service".split(' ').join('+');`

Comment: so will that just work for customer service? I would like it so it works with any multiple keyword search

Comment: that code wont work, var removeSymb = "keyword1".split(' ').join('+'); still only recognises the first word and still requires an +

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `str` is the string containing your text:

```
var removeSymb = str.replace(/\s/g,'+');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for this.

```
var string = ' ';
var reg = new RegExp(string, 'g');

str = str.replace(reg, '');
```